# Task List in a multithreaded environment - "enumeration operation may not execute"

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I have a Task factory thats kicking off many tasks, sometimes over 1000. I add every Task to a list, and remove it when the Task has completed.

```
var scan = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                return operation.Run();
            }, token.Token
            );

            operations.Add(scan);
```

When a task Completes:

```
var finishedTask = scan.ContinueWith(resultTask =>
                OperationComplete(resultTask),
                TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion
                );

public virtual void OperationComplete(Task task)
    {
        operations.Remove(task);
    }
```

When all are complete:

```
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(operations.ToArray(),
         result =>
         {
             AllOperationsComplete();
         }, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
```

Then, at certain points in my application I want to get the count of running tasks. (This is where I get the error: "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.")

```
    public int Count()
    {  
        int running = operations.Count<Task>((x) => x.Status == TaskStatus.Running);
        return running;
    }
```

A couple questions:

1) Should I even worry about removing the tasks from the list? The list could easily be in the 1000s.

2) Whats the best way to make Count() safe? Creating a new List and adding `operations` to it will still enumerate the collection, if I remember right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you need to lock to make sure only one thread accesses the list at a time (whether that's during removal or counting) or you should use a concurrent collection. Don't forget that `Count(Func<T, bool>)` needs to iterate over the collection in order to perform the count - it's like using a `foreach` loop... and you can't modify a collection (in general) while you're iterating over it.

I suspect that [`ConcurrentBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) is an appropriate choice here - and as you're using TPL, presumably you have the .NET 4 concurrent collections available...

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you don't modify a collection while you're iterating.  Most collections don't support that.  A `lock` would likely suffice.
But, you'll likely want to revisit the design.  Locking a collection for an extended period of time will likely kill any performance gains you where hoping to get from asynchronous Tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code is already checking status as part of the count call, and assuming you aren't doing the count until after all tasks are in the collection, just not removing them seems like the simplest answer. Make sure to actually measure perf differences if you decide to switch out List for something else, especially if the number of times that Count call is done is low relative to the size of the collection. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
to keep track of your tasks (Concurrentbags don't let you remove specific items).

```
ConcurrentDictionary<Task, string> runningTasks = new ConcurrentDictionary<Task, string>();

Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }).ContinueWith(processedTask => {
        var outString; // A string we don't care about
        runningTasks.TryRemove(processedTask, out outString);
    });

runningTasks.TryAdd(task, "Hello I'm a task");
// Add lots more tasks to runningTasks

while (runningTasks.Count > 0)
{
     Console.WriteLine("I'm still waiting...");
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

If you wanna do a proper "`WaitAll`" (requires LINQ):

```
    try
    {
        Task[] keys = runningTasks.Keys.Select(x => x).ToArray();
        Task.WaitAll(keys);
    }
    catch { } // WaitAll will always throw an exception.
```

Hope it helps.